# Images in list view jumping from row to row

Tags: java, android, image, listview, android-listview

I am using a ListView with images, also I have an image loader. The problem is that when there is a fast scrolling the images appears on wrong rows, after short time when the scrolling stops every thing gets back in place.

Here is my adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyObj> 
{
    int                     layoutResourceId;
    List<MyObj> data;
    Activity                activity;
    int                     rowViewId;

    public MyAdapter(Activity activity, int layoutResourceId, List<MyObj> data)
    {
        super(activity, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.data = data;
        rowViewId = R.layout.my_layout.xml;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView title;
        public ImageView image;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;


        if (row == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            row = layoutInflater.inflate(rowViewId, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        final MyObj obj = data.get(position);

        if (event != null) 
        {
            holder.title.setText(event.getTitle());
            ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader();
            imageLoader.loadImageFromAppServer(obj.getImageName(), holder.image);
        }

        return row;
    }
}
```

Is there any thing I can do to prevent this unwanted behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is being loaded asynchronously by `loadImageFromAppServer`. When it arrives from the server, your `holder.image` object is already reused by another row that doesn't represent the same data it did when you asked your `ImageLoader` object to download the image. You need to implement a way to tell the `ImageLoader` object to cancel the previous download request.

Comment: Of course, but how can you go about doing that really?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but I need the previous image download to finish in order to get this image.

Comment: I think caching the images would be a good solution... this way `loadImageFromAppServer` would take a fraction of the time.

Comment: What image loader library are you using?

Comment: Handling image loading is not something trivial as some tutorials suggest. Why don't you use some great libraries out there like Universal Image Loader or Square Picasso?